# Check file name suffix if .js

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if file name suffix is type **JavaScript** (JS files end with *.js)
for that I use the following code which works

```
var ext = aa.getName().substr(aa.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Now the problem is that if the file is named `file2.json` I'm still getting true (it's return json) 
My question is if there a better way to do it i.e. given any file name like
`file1.xml`, `file2.js`, `file3.json` or `file4.html`, it will return true  just for `file2`.

Comment: `/.*\.js$/` or `/\.js$/` should work, but where do you do this? node or browser?

Comment: @baao - I use it in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can work

```js
function check(str){
    if(str.match(/(\w*)\.js$/) == null){
        console.log('false');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        console.log('true');
        return true;
    }
}
     
check('file1.xml');
check('file2.js');
check('file3.json');
check('file4.html');
```

Comment: Thanks so should I Do some if statment to the object that im getting as result from str.match and to see if this object NE null ?

Comment: just make check return true or false, if it is not null return true

Comment: The dot is wrong, it matches anything. Should be escaped.

Comment: @marvel308 , maybe the `\w` should be `\S` , just to make the solution more universal , have seen files that start with `@` , example fancybox :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let isJS = function(filename) {
    return /\.js$/i.test(filename)
}


console.log(isJS("asd.json")) // false;
console.log(isJS("asdjs"))    // false;
console.log(isJS("asd.js"))   // true;
console.log(isJS("asd.JS"))   // true;
```

Comment: My bad, edited; There's no need to downvote for a missing `\ `. an edit would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if string ends with `.js` with the following function:

```
function isJavascriptFile(str) {
  var regex = /\.js$/;
  var match = str.match(regex);

  return match !== null;
}
```

According to your code you would use it like this:

```
var name = aa.getName();
isJavascriptFile(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for this case better not using regex,

```
  var arr = [
    'file1.xml',
    'file2.js',
    'file3.json',
    'file4.html'
  ];

  for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++){
    if(returnExtension(arr[i]) == 'js') {
      alert('Your file is: ' + arr[i])
    }
  }

  function returnExtension(filename){
    var a = filename.split(".");
    if( a.length === 1 || ( a[0] === "" && a.length === 2 ) ) {
      return "";
    }
    return a.pop();
  }
```

my working example  is here https://jsfiddle.net/gat8mx7y/

Answer (score 0):

You've to modify your code a little bit, you're almost right:

```
funciton isJavascriptFile(fileName){
   var ext = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
   if(ext === 'js'){ return true; } 
   return false;
}

if(isJavascriptFile(aa.getName()) ) {
  console.log("file is javascript");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 //function GetJSName(){
  var filename="sample.js";
  var name = filename.split('.')[0];
  alert(name);

//};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```